# MoxieManager TinyMCE Integration

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I just purchased the MoxieManager plugin for Tiny MCE and got it up and running very quickly. However, I need to add in some logic to only show the images YOU uploaded.

Thus, I created a insert to take place into a database table when you upload an image. This will store the user_id, company_id and the name of the image. So I can reference whose images are whose.

Problem: I can't seem to get the API to work. I found the following which "intercepts" any uploads:

```
moxman.upload({
path: '/files/images',
onupload: function(args) {
   console.log(args.files);
}
```

});

I was going to change the "path:" to my controller function that does the insert. However, I can't seem to find where to place this Javascript above. What file does it go in?

Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Source: http://www.moxiemanager.com/documentation/index.php/js_upload_onupload

"This callback enables you to intercept the uploaded files."

Answer (score 0):

I expect you might have found a work around for this question, but to anyone else trying to work this out here is my solution:

```
tinymce.init({
    //tinymce configuration
    ...
    moxiemanager_onupload: function(args) {
       //args is an Object containing File Objects 
    }
});
```

I don't think this is documented anywhere really, but I found inspiration from http://www.moxiemanager.com/documentation/index.php/js_browse